# how to properly query table where value can be in one or another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an original table test1, parent-child table test2 and table with searched values test3. Table test2 includes top-parent values in another column. When any of the values in test 3 is searched, we need to select the parent and all the child values.

```
create table test1 (ID int);
insert into test1 (ID) values (123),(124),(125),(126),(127),(128),(129)

create table test2 (IDC int, IDP int)
insert into test2 (IDC, IDP) values (124,123),(125,123),(127,126),(129,128)

create table test3 (ID int) 
insert into test3 (ID) values (123),(127)

select * from test1 
where 
ID in (select IDC from test2
             where IDC in (select ID from test3) 
             or IDP in (select ID from test3)) 
or ID in (select IDP from test2 
             where IDC in (select ID from test3) 
             or IDP in (select ID from test3))
```

Is there a nicer way to write this query?

Thank you, Aleš

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the ID's need to exist in table1 when the table3 ID matches with the ID's in table2?

Here's a more concise solution:

```
select *
from test1 t1
where exists (
 select 1 
 from test2 t2
 join test3 t3 on t3.ID in (t2.IDC, t2.IDP)
 where t1.ID in (t2.IDC, t2.IDP)
);
```

Comment: marked as best answer due to speed (3s on live data vs 12s with my attempt), simplicity and readability. THX!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
select * from test1 t1
where exists(select 1 from test2 t2
             where (t1.ID = t2.IDC or t1.ID = IDP)
               and exists(select 1 from test3
                          where t2.IDC = ID or t2.IDP = ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be another approach

```
SELECT * FROM #test1
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT VAL.X FROM #test2 T2
INNER JOIN #test3 T3 ON T2.IDC = T3.ID OR T2.IDP = T3.ID
CROSS APPLY(VALUES (IDC),(IDP),(ID)) VAL(X)
)
```

**Result:**

```
ID
-----
123
124
125
126
127
```

Comment: don't know why, but on a larger dataset in test1 (even with test3 filtering) is returning more rows... Will try to produce bigger test1 sample.